# AngularJs unicode select fontawesome

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, unicode, font-awesome

I want to display fontawesome icons in my selectbox.

For static purposes I succeeded with the following code:

```
ng-options=" '&#xf0e7;' +l.Name for l in locations"
```

My only problem is that I need to dynamicly show the icon according to the type of my location. When I fix this in my controller and make name as following:

```
if(logic){
  $scope.locations[0].name = "&#xf0e7;" + $scope.locations[0].name;
}
```

This shows the unicode as plain text. What am i doing wrong or am I missing something?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the unicode literal in javascript:

```
$scope.locations[0].name = "\uf0e7"
```

that's the unicode literal notation.